# How can I learn if 2 NSStrings are almost same to eachother?

Tags: xcode, nsstring, compare

I take a string from user,and I make some iterations on it.

For example the user entered the text @"The weather is beautiful today.";

I want to make same iterations when user entered `"the wether is beatifullll tdy"` or `"th weather is beatttiful  tooodayy"` or `"the weatherrr iss beautiful toda"`.

Here is my code:

```
// (str is the user's text)

if ([str rangeOfString:@"hello" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
// when user entered helloo I want make to same iteration,
// but in this case the program goes else part.        
    [array insertObject:@"hello" atIndex:s];
} else if ([str rangeOfString:@"You are so beautiful" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound ) {
    [dizi insertObject:@"I know, Thanks" atIndex:s];
} else if ([str rangeOfString:@"Have Lunch?" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
    [array insertObject:@"Yes,I have" atIndex:s];
} else {
    [array insertObject:@"please,speak english" atIndex:s];
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do fuzzy matching...

Comment: he has 2 strings and wants to know how much they match -- how close they are -- huffman distance could work

Comment: @trojanfoe thats the word I was looking FOR :D

Comment: I want flexible comparison between 2 nsstrings,I cannot write all options for all words.Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, you use fuzzy matching.

Comment: @trojanfoe thx,I am searching fuzzy matcihing in xcode,it looks like difficult.I hope , I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StringScore for fuzzy matching:

> https://github.com/thetron/StringScore

Example:

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello world!";

CGFloat result1 = [testString scoreAgainst:@"Hello world!"];
CGFloat result2 = [testString scoreAgainst:@"world"];
CGFloat result3 = [testString scoreAgainst:@"wXrld" fuzziness:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8]];
CGFloat result4 = [testString scoreAgainst:@"world" fuzziness:nil options:NSStringScoreOptionFavorSmallerWords];
CGFloat result5 = [testString scoreAgainst:@"world" fuzziness:nil options:(NSStringScoreOptionFavorSmallerWords & NSStringScoreOptionReducedLongStringPenalty)];
CGFloat result6 = [testString scoreAgainst:@"HW"]; // abbreviation matching example

NSLog(@"Result 1 = %f", result1);
NSLog(@"Result 2 = %f", result2);
NSLog(@"Result 3 = %f", result3);
NSLog(@"Result 4 = %f", result4);
NSLog(@"Result 5 = %f", result5);
NSLog(@"Result 6 = %f", result6);
```

Output:

```
Result 1 = 1.000000
Result 2 = 0.425000
Result 3 = 0.271528
Result 4 = 0.250000
Result 5 = 0.425000
Result 6 = 0.645833
```